# Inheritance java-bank account (java)

Tags: java, inheritance

I am working on an inheritance bank account which has 5 classes.In one of the classes(InterestFreeDeposit) ,the account should be created with at least 10 $. How should I write the code of this part?
here is what I have done until now:

**superClass:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
public class Account {
    private String owner;
    private double balance;
    private int accountNumber;
    private double interestRate;
        public Account( String owner,double balance, int accountNumber , double interestRate){
            this.balance=balance;
            this.owner=owner;
            this.accountNumber=accountNumber;
            this.interestRate=interestRate;
        }
        public void deposit(double amount) {
                if(amount>0) {
                    this.balance+=amount;
                }

        }
        public void withdraw(double amount) {
                if(amount>0 && balance>=amount) {
                    this.balance-=amount;
                }
        }
        public double getBalance() {
            return balance;
        }
        public void setBalance(double amount) {
            this.balance = amount;
        }

        public String getOwner() {
            return owner;
        }


public void setOwner(String owner) {
            this.owner = owner;
        }
        public int getAccountNumber() {
            return accountNumber;
        }
        public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        }
        public double getInterestRate() {
            return interestRate;
        }
        public double setInterestRate(double interestRate) {
            //System.out.println("Enter the period(month):");

            return this.balance +=balance * interestRate/100;
        }
```

**subClass(InterestFrreClass):**

```
public class InterestFreeDeposit extends Account {
public InterestFreeDeposit(String owner, double balance, int accountNumber, double interestRate) {
    super(owner, balance, accountNumber, interestRate);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public void interest() {
    super.setInterestRate(0.0) ;


    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the check when the value is set, which in this case happens in the constructor of `InterestFreeDeposit`. The question is how you want to react when the value is below `10`. You could throw an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
public InterestFreeDeposit(String owner, double balance, int accountNumber, double interestRate) {
    super(owner, balance, accountNumber, interestRate);
    if(balance < 10){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("balance must be at least 10");
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that `IllegalArgumentException` is an unchecked exception, meaning that the caller of the constructor is not forced to deal with it if it is thrown.

Comment: The cleanest method would probably be, by introducing a factory method, which checks if the balance provided is sufficient, and only if it is, a `InterestFreeDeposit` is created, else the Exception is thrown

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator in your subclass constuctor to default to a `10.0` minimum value:

```
public class InterestFreeDeposit extends Account {
     public InterestFreeDeposit(String owner, double balance, int accountNumber, double interestRate) {
         super(owner, balance < 10.0 ? 10.0 : balance, accountNumber, interestRate);
     }
}
```

A ternary operator can be seen as an inline if. So you have following structure:

```
condition ? condition is true : condition is false
```

In the above snippet it just checks if the provided balance is below the `10.0`. if it is it just sets it to 10, else it is passed along:

```
balance < 10.0 ? 10.0 : balance
```

Comment: So you just modify the data and "create money"?

Comment: @f1sh the OP didn't specify *what* exactly should happen if insufficient balance is provided. So I am *creating* money, yes. If he wants to throw an error, then your answer is probably better